# mean of 10 variables with different starting point (SAS)

Tags: sas, mean

I have 18 numerical variables pm25_total2000 to pm25_total2018

Each person have a starting year between 2013 and 2018, we can call that variable "reqyear".

Now I want to calculate mean for each persons 10 years before the starting year.

For example if a person have starting year 2015 I want mean(of pm25_total2006-pm25_total2015)

Or if a person have starting year 2013 I want mean(of pm25_total2004-pm25_total2013)

How to do this?

```
data _null_;
 set scapkon;
   reqyear=substr(iCDate,1,4)*1;
 call symput('reqy',reqyear);
 run;


data scatm;
 set scapkon;
 
/* Medelvärde av 10 år innan rekryteringsår */
pm25means=mean(of pm25_total%eval(&reqy.-9)-pm25_total%eval(&reqy.));

run;
```

%eval(&reqy.-9) will be constant value (the same value for all as for the first person) , in my case 2007
That doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the mean with a traditional loop.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array x x2000-x2018;

  call missing(sum, mean, n);
  do _n_ = 1 to 10;
    v = x ( start - 1999 -_n_ );
    if not missing(v) then do;
      sum + v;
      n + 1;
    end;
  end;

  if n then mean = sum / n;
run;
```

If you want to flex your SAS skill, you can use POKE and PEEK concepts to copy a fixed length slice (i.e. a fixed number of array elements) of an array to another array and compute the mean of the slice.

Example:

You will need to add sentinel elements and range checks on start to prevent errors when start-10 < 2000.

```
data have;
  length id start x2000-x2018 8;
  do id = 1 to 15;
    start = 2013 + mod(id,6);
    array x x2000-x2018;
    do over x;
      x = _n_;
      _n_+1;
    end;
    output;
  end;

  format x: 5.;
run;

data want;
  length id start mean10yrPriorStart 8;

  set have;
  array x x2000-x2018;
  array slice(10) _temporary_;

  call pokelong (
         peekclong ( addrlong ( x(start-1999-10) ) , 10*8 ) ,
         addrlong ( slice (1))
       );

  mean10yrPriorStart = mean(of slice(*));
run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- use an array and loop
- index the array with years
- accumulate the sum of the values
- accumulate the count to account for any missing values
- divide to obtain the mean value

```
data want;

set have;

array _pm(2000:2018) pm25_total2000 - pm25_total2018;

do year=reqyear to (reqyear-9) by -1;
    *add totals;
    total = sum(total, _pm(year));
    *add counts;
    nyears = sum(nyears,not missing(_pm(year)));
end;

*accounts for possible missing years;
mean = total/nyears;

run;
```

Note this loop goes in reverse (start year to 9 years previous) because it's slightly easier to understand this way IMO.
If you have no missing values you can remove the nyears step, but not a bad thing to include anyways.

Comment: First the counting of number of non-missing values.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: My first answer did not address the OP's question, so this a redux.

For this solution, I used Richard's code for generating test data. However, I added a line to randomly add missing values.

```
      x = _n_;
      if ranuni(1) < .1 then x = .;
      _n_+1;
```

This alternative does not perform any checks for missing values. The `sum()` and `n()` functions inherently handle missing values appropriately. The loop over the dynamic slice of the data array only transfers the value to a temporary array. The final sum and count is performed on the temp array outside of the loop.

```
data want;
set have;
array x(2000:2018) x:;
array t(10) _temporary_;

j = 1;
do i = start-9 to start;
    t(j) = x(i);
    j + 1;
end;

sum = sum(of t(*));
cnt = n(of t(*));
mean = sum / cnt;

drop x: i j;
run;
```

Result:

```
id  start   sum cnt mean
1   2014    72  7   10.285714286
2   2015    305 10  30.5
3   2016    458 9   50.888888889
4   2017    631 9   70.111111111
```